# Is there any way to insert a unique ID to Ledger Nano X?

Tags: go, security, stellar, ledger-nano-s, hardware-wallet

My current project involves utilising the Ledger Nano X hardware wallet, and I need to assign a unique identifier to the device. Specifically, I am looking to input a unique ID  into Ledger Nano X hardware wallet.

I looked at the Ledger documentation, but couldn't find a way to add a unique ID to the Ledger Nano X hardware wallet for my project. but i have seen some articles using "APDU" and inserting and installing a application.Currently im using golang. most of the packages are deprecated

https://shop.ledger.com/products/ledger-nano-x